# Why both data have same standard deviation?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

[image]

But I am curious why the standard deviation for both data is same. 
I think because data 2 is "100 - data 1".

Comment: $var(X+a)=var(X)$ and $var(aX)=a^2var(X)$ for a real number $a$ and a random variable $X$. With those, can you prove why $var(100-X)=var(X)$ where X is your data set? (Equal variances is the same as equal standard deviations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still would like you to try to prove it, but I’ll give some intuition about those two identities I gave.

Remember that variance (and standard deviation) have something to do with how spread out your data are.

$var(X+a)=var(X)$ means that if you take data with some amount of spread and slide them up or down the number line, you do not change the spread.

$var(X)=var(-X)$ is not quite what I gave, but it’ll be part of your proof. The intuition here is that you’re just spinning it around, taking a mirror image. The data are as spread out as their reflection.

Together, $var(100-X)=var(X)$ means that you flip the data to the mirror image and then slide along the number line, but you do not change the spread.

Capisce?

Comment: what is the meaning of `Capisce`?

Comment: that's Italian for "do you comprehend ?"

Answer (score 2):

To supplement @Dave's answer, take a look at the following histograms which have the same x-axis. Data2 is just a shifted version of Data1 and therefore the standard deviation, which is a measure of spread, shouldn't change.

[image]

R code to generate histograms:

```
x <- 100*rgamma(1000, 6, 2) #Simulate some data
hist(x, xlim=c(0,100))
hist(100-x, xlim=c(0,100))
```

Comment: Thanks. well-plotted histogram. May I know how do you plot the histogram?

Comment: @aan see the update.

Comment: @knrumsey Good illustration. However, simulating from the gamma distribution would produce realizations that cluster around a mean that is much lower than what I see here given the parameters you specified. Right?

Comment: @Tom, that is correct. I didn't put too much thought into which distribution I simulated from. Just wanted draws between 0 and 100.

Comment: @Thomas Bilach, realizing that I misunderstood your question. Thanks for pointing this out, I've updated the post to reflect the fact that I multiplied the data by 100.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to this question can be expressed in more elemental terms. Beginning with the formula for the sample standard deviation

$$
s_{x} = \sqrt{\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \overline{x})^2} }{n - 1}},
$$

I want to draw your attention to the expression $(x_i - \overline{x})$ in the numerator. Ignore the summation notation for the purposes of this answer. Note, we decrement the sample mean (i.e., $\overline{x}$) from each realization of $x_{i}$. If we were to increase or decrease each $x_{i}$ by the same amount, the mean will change. However, the distance of each realization of $x_{i}$ from that central tendency *remains the same*. In other words, each deviation from the *mean* is the same.

Subtracting each $x_{i}$ from a constant (e.g., $100 - x_{i}$) flips the vector of values to its mirror image, then slides it along the number line by a constant amount. Suppose the first realization of $x_{1}$ = 20 and $\overline{x}$ = 4. In keeping with the foregoing expression,

$$
(20 - 4) = 16,
$$

which is the deviation from the sample mean. Now, assume we don't move along the number line just yet and we simply put a negative sign in front of each $x_{i}$, such that we have $-(x_{i})$; this flips the sign of the mean as well. The first realization, $x_{1}$, is now $-20$. Again, substituting $-20$ into the expression,

$$
(-20-(-4)) =-16,
$$

which is the same number of units away from the mean. Note, squared deviations result in a positive number, so the numerator remains the same. You can run this code in R which builds upon @knrumsey's insightful response, but breaks it down further:

```
x <- rnorm(10000, 30, 5) # Simulates 10,000 random deviates from the normal distribution

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
hist(x, xlim = c(0, 100), col = "blue")
hist(-x, xlim = c(-100, 0), col = "red")  # Note the -x, it simply flips the sign (mirror image)
hist(x, xlim = c(0, 100), col = "blue")
hist(100-x, xlim = c(0, 100), col = "red")  # Subtracting x from 100 shifts values along the x-axis
```

[image]

The first row of plots shows how the realizations translate when we negate each $x_{i}$. The second row shows what happens when each $x_{i}$ is subtracted from 100; the translation first flips then slides across the number line. The *spread* of the distribution is unaffected by this.

Answer (score 1):

changes period to period in DATA 1 identical to the negative changes in DATA 2

OBS     DATA 1     FIRST DIF           DATA 2    FIRST DIFF

1        30         NA                   70        NA

2        40         10                   60        -10

3        80         40                   20        -40

4        30        -50                   70         50

5        20        -10                   80         10

6        33         13                   67        -13

7        33          0                   67          0

8        33          0                   67          0

9        33          0                   67          0

CONTINUING STEPS TO UNCOVER THE BASIC RELATIONSHIP OF DATA1 AND DATA2:

I took the series DATA1 and computed the ACF ... here it is ..

[image]

AND for DATA2   here

[image]

...note that not only are the standard deviations the same but the ACF's are the same.

Comment: This is an interesting perspective, but I believe it would need more explanation to be understood by many readers.

Comment: @IrishStat, thanks. do you mind to explain more?

Comment: i added some material to my response detailing how differenced data period to period  ( val2-val1,val3-val2,.. val9-val8) for both original series DATA1 and DATA2 were complements of each other

Comment: @IrishStat. Noted. what is the meaning of `Q.E.D` and `OBS`?

Comment: Q.E.D.  is math (latin abbreviation) talk for "what was asked to be demonstrated /proven has been proved"  . In data matrix talk .. we have rows (observations) and columns (characteristics/variables  per row ) .There are 18 values all in all. There are 9 rows and 2 columns . The rows are sometime called observations and the columns are sometimes called variables or classes as in this case. You have two classes ( data1 AND data2) and 9 observations per class thus 18 values.

Comment: "QED" is not a valid remark to make following the display of a table of numbers, because nothing so far has been proved or even explained.

Comment: it is  comedic ! ... not to be taken seriously except by some .. .what was asked to be detailed that "changes period to period in DATA 1 identical to the negative changes in DATA 2"  .

Comment: An explicit connection between those assertions and the result is needed.  What is interesting is your use of *successive differences* ("changes period to period" in an otherwise unordered dataset) to characterize the standard deviation of the dataset.  In other words, you appear to be claiming that the set of equalities $$x_{i+1}-x_i = -(y_{i+1}-y_i)$$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, n-1$ implies $$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar y)^2.$$ That's true, but it does need to be shown: you can't just exhibit a table of numbers and declare "QED"!

Comment: I agree that this must be ALGEBRAICALLY proven BUT not by me .... I simply observed/deduced based upon a relatively long period of having exclusively studied time series that there was an underlying mechanism PERHAPS reflecting a similar autoprojective scheme /pattern WITHIN each of the two given series. Is there anything positive that you can contribute to this ?

Comment: I believe my interactions here have already been positive, by reframing your assertion and showing clearly what a good answer would need to include.  This is *not* a time series question, btw.

Comment: i deleted the Q.E.D. . for some unknown/curious reason to me first differences  ( a time series statistic) yielded a valid observation regarding equivalences.  Additionally the auto-covariance function yielded a similarity .. ( see my modified answer )

Comment: The reason is that regardless of how each dataset is ordered, you can recover all its values *up to an additive constant* by assuming a value $x$ for $x_1$ and finding $x_2=x + (x_2-x_1),$ $x_3=x_2 + (x_3-x_2),$ and so on. Thus, when the first differences of one dataset are some multiple $\lambda$ of the first differences in another (paired) dataset, the ratios of the SDs is $|\lambda|.$ This directly results from the calculus of units of measurement, because the choices of $x$ and $\lambda$ merely establish an origin and unit of measurement for the data.

Comment: tu that was helpful